# Regular Expression (string compare)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have written this in javascript (web) but since i try to use RegExpression it should work almost the same.

I have a string with some coordinates in it seperated by a space charakter.

```
var coords = "0:0 0:0:0 1:0:1 0:0:0:1";
var part = "0:0";
```

I want to have all the coordinates beginning with the value of part ("0:0");

What I tryed is something like:

```
var reg = new RegExp(part+"*");
alert(coords .match(reg));
```

But it seems not to work propperly.

It should match "0:0" and "0:0:0" and "0:0:0:1" but NOT "1:0:1" (edit)

Anyone has an idea?!

Kind regards!

Comment: Try this var reg = new RegExp(part,"*");

Comment: You are not clear. Does it match `0:0:0` and/or `0:0:0:1`?

Comment: it should match "0:0" and "0:0:0" and "0:0:0:1" but NOT "1:0:1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex:

```
var reg = new RegExp("(^|\\s)(" + part + "\\S*)", "g");
```

that is to match all non-space characters after `0:0` and stop when it hits a space or line end.

Comment: still not working :/ prints out only one time "0:0", I've read about it but didn't knew that it contains line end, do i maybe have to set modifiers?!

Comment: @marius: You need to use global switch to capture all the strings, see edited answer now.

Comment: ah okay seems legit but what i get back aren't the coordinates it's three times "0:0"

Comment: Actually `\S` should be `\\S` I just tested and corrected my code. Check it now.